# Jquery can't get value from input field

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I use to create and update services in my database. The form is actually the same form for both, with the exception that it uses PHP to determine if it is for creating or editing a service (by naming the form something different for both) and prefilling form fields if it is for editing.

When I am using the form for creating a new service, I use the following Jquery code to get the value of the service name and it works properly:

```
 var service = $('#ServiceName').val();
    if(confirm("Create Service " + service)){
    //Code in here on confirmation
    }
```

This returns the name of the service without issue, however, when I am using the form for editing and the value for the input is prefilled, the same exact code no longer works, it just returns blank where service variable goes. If I try and edit the name of the service, that won't show up either. To be clear, this isn't affecting how it is entered into the database, that works just fine for both create and edit, it only won't show up in the confirmation alert box.

I think it might have something to do with it being autofilled, but I am not sure. Again, the forms are exactly the same except for the names of the forms themselves. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Comment: What `HTML` Element are you using as the input?

Comment: Are you submitting the form with AJAX or is the page being refreshed when you submit?

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces issue. Are you duplicating ID in same page?

Comment: @Difster I am using Ajax to submit the form for both.

Comment: If you were to copy/paste this: `<input type="text" id="ServiceName" value="XXX">` as your `HTML`, the `jQuery` should return `XXX`.

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you, that was the issue, I had a duplicate id on the page. I have fixed the issue and it works now.